# Non generic type Fields can not be used with type argument

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When I try to add [Source Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/source-filtering-usage.html) to my `SearchRequest` I get error

> The non generic type 'Fields' can not be used with type arguments

on `Fields`. here is the code snippet:

```
var request = new SearchRequest<ElasticSearchJsonObject.Rootobject>(Nest.Indices.Index("myindex"), Types.All)
    {
         From = 0,
         Size = 10,
         Query = query,
         Source = new SourceFilter
          {
               Includes = "*",
               Excludes = Fields<ElasticSearchJsonObject.Rootobject>(p => p.footer)
          }
    };
```

Error appear in Excludes Fields even when I try `Fields("footer")` directly.
This is how documentation suggests.

I am using Elastic Search 6.0.2 and NEST 6.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [`Fields`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/6.x/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/Infer/Fields/Fields.cs), it supports implicit conversions from several types, including

- Infer.Fields e.g.

  `Nest.Infer.Fields<ElasticSearchJsonObject.Rootobject>(p => p.footer)`
- string e.g.

  `"footer"`
- System.Reflection.PropertyInfo e.g.

  `typeof(ElasticSearchJsonObject.Rootobject).GetProperty("footer")`

It's essentially a version of `Field` that supports multiple fields. [Check out the documentation on `Field` inference.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html)

Comment: thank you, looks like it is difficult to find documentation. Three people ended up on three different pages. I tried this `typeof(ElasticSearchJsonObject.Rootobject).GetProperty("footer")`, don't know why it was giving error then but not now

Comment: Would love feedback on how we could better organise and improve the documentation: would you mind opening an issue to discuss: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues?

Comment: Added over here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/3183